# How would I scan over a string with someone's name and create initials for it?

Tags: c

So basically I need to get an input from a user (user's name) and then iterate over the user's name and create a new string of the initials. Then I have to output the initials. I'm pretty confused on how to do this in C.

One thing to keep in mind is that I have to use pointers. I can't use array operations as stated in my homework instructions. I think I'm on the right path, but I'm confused on how to concatenate characters to a string. Can someone help me out here?

Here is the code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *name = malloc(100);
    char c[5];
    char *initials = c;

    printf("Enter your full name in the following format 'First Middle Last':\n");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++){
        if(name[i] == ' '){
            strcat(&name[i + 1], initials);
            printf("%s", initials);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Example input: `Charles Edwin Roberts`

Example output: `C.E.R`

Comment: Add an example of input,output.

Comment: you should look into how `strcat()` works.

Comment: How flexible do you have to be?  If someone types '`John M. Doe`', will you be able to handle that?  What about `J.M.Doe`? (Note spacing!)  What about '`john michael doe`'?  Do remember that there are people without middle names (I know this — I don't have one); in some countries, some people are given just a single name, though that is relatively unusual these days.

Comment: Note that you can only concatenate to a null-terminated string.  Your array `c` (via the pointer `initials`) is not a null-terminated string because it is uninitialized.  Also, the order of the arguments for `strcat()` is `char *strcat(char *target, const char *source)` (with `restrict` qualifiers on both pointers in C99, indicating that the two strings may not overlap).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Does the format posted '**F**irst **M**iddle **L**ast' imply that a user must input `John Michael Doe` instead of `john michael doe`?

Comment: @sunqingyao: yes, but users don't read the instructions, so the code must decide what to do when the data arrives without any capitals.

Comment: Note that you've not allocated enough space for the string of initials if the output must include the dots.  You must allow for the null terminator (so you need at least `char c[6];` and possibly more).  You also need to deal with the eccentricities of human input.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler assume the user always inputs First Middle Last. I need the initials to be F.M.L. Can you write the code that needs to go in the if statement? I'm totally lost as to how to do that in C.

Answer (score 1):

I would scan the input manually, spotting when I find the first letter of a word and copying the upper case version of that to the array of initials, with a following dot; subsequent letters of a word would be ignored; non-letters would mark the end of a word.

#### Source code (`caps.c`)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[100];
    while (printf("Please enter the name (First Middle Last): ") > 0 &&
           fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin) != 0)
    {
        char *s = name;
        int inword = 0;
        unsigned char c;
        char initials[20] = "";
        char *p = initials;
        char *e = initials + sizeof(initials) - 2;
        while ((c = (unsigned char)*s++) != '\0')
        {
            if (!isalpha(c))
                inword = 0;
            else if (inword == 0)
            {
                *p++ = toupper(c);
                *p++ = '.';
                inword = 1;
                if (p >= e)
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (p > initials)
            *(p - 1) = '\0';   /* Zap the final dot to meet the spec */

        printf("Initials: %s\n", initials);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

I decline to run the program repeatedly, so I added a simple loop.  Since `printf()` returns the number of characters it prints, the `> 0` test is safe.  If you're concerned about your I/O package not flushing standard output before reading from standard input, you could add `&& fflush(stdout) == 0` to the loop conditions.

#### Sample run

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror caps.c -o caps  
$ caps
Please enter the name (First Middle Last): Charles Edwin Roberts
Initials: C.E.R
Please enter the name (First Middle Last): john michael doe
Initials: J.M.D
Please enter the name (First Middle Last): john.m.doe   
Initials: J.M.D
Please enter the name (First Middle Last): the artist formerly known as "prince"
Initials: T.A.F.K.A.P
Please enter the name (First Middle Last): he who has far too many words in his name was here     
Initials: H.W.H.F.T.M.W.I.H
Please enter the name (First Middle Last):     antiquated    (old)     man!!!
Initials: A.O.M
Please enter the name (First Middle Last): ajaykumar
Initials: A
Please enter the name (First Middle Last):   @(#)$!!!
Initials: 
Please enter the name (First Middle Last): 
$
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of approaches you can take. You can *tokenize* the input with functions like `strtok` and `strsep`, you can find each space with functions like `strchr`, or, probably the most efficient for short input like names is simply to loop over your input using a pointer and find all instances where you have a `' '` followed by a *letter*. To place a `'.'` in between each initial, simply add a `'.'` before each subsequent initial *after* the first initial has been added.

Since you know your initials will include the first character of the string, you can take the first character as an initial and then loop over the remainder of the input. By looking for a `' '` followed by a *letter*, you avoid the circumstance where you have multiple spaces separating the parts of the name. (if the parts of the name can be `tab` separated, you can include that as a check as well). You also need to determine a maximum number of characters can make up initials. This just prevents the input of 18 words resulting in an 18 character set of initials.

You can either pass the maximum number as a parameter or you can use a global constant or `#define`. Note: when adding a `'.'` in between the initials your space required for the initials will be `n` (initials) `+ n - 1` (`'.'`s) or simply `2 * n - 1`. Adding the *nul-terminating* character, that equates to `2 * n` characters total storage in your initials array.

A simple approach could be something like the following:

```
enum { MAXI = 7, MAXC = 128 };   /* constants for max initials and chars */
...
char *initials (char *intls, char *s)
{
    int n = 0;

    if (!intls || !s)
        return NULL;

    if (isalpha(*s))
        intls[n++] = toupper(*s);              /* add first initial */

    for (; n < MAXI && *s && *(s + 1); s++)
        if (*s == ' ' && isalpha(*(s + 1))) {
            intls[n++] = '.';                  /* add . separator before */
            intls[n++] = toupper (*(s + 1));   /* each remaining initial */
        }

    return intls;
}
```

You can use it in a number of ways. One simple example that limits the number of initials accepted to `4` by setting the constant limit to `2 * n - 1` (e.g. the constant created by `enum { MAXI = 7...`) would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

enum { MAXI = 7, MAXC = 128 };   /* constants for max initials and chars */

char *initials (char *intls, char *s);

int main (void) {

    char intls[MAXI + 1] = {0};
    char name[MAXC] = {0};
    size_t len = 0;

    printf("Enter your full name ('First Middle Last'): ");
    if (!fgets (name, MAXC, stdin)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid name\n");
        return 1;
    }

    len = strlen (name);    /* get length and validate min   */
    if (len > 1)            /* of 2 chars to acount for '\n' */
        name[len - 1] = 0;  /* remove '\n' */
    else {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: empty string for name.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!initials (intls, name)) return 1;

    printf ("\n name     : %s\n initials : %s\n\n", name, intls);

    return 0;
}

char *initials (char *intls, char *s)
{
    int n = 0;

    if (!intls || !s)
        return NULL;

    if (isalpha(*s))
        intls[n++] = toupper(*s);

    for (; n < MAXI && *s && *(s + 1); s++)
        if (*s == ' ' && isalpha(*(s + 1))) {
            intls[n++] = '.';
            intls[n++] = toupper (*(s + 1));
        }

    return intls;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/initials
Enter your full name ('First Middle Last'): john joe lee

 name     : john joe lee
 initials : J.J.L

$ ./bin/initials
Enter your full name ('First Middle Last'): j

 name     : j
 initials : J

$ ./bin/initials
Enter your full name ('First Middle Last'): john joe lee frank marvin

 name     : john joe lee frank marvin
 initials : J.J.L.F

$ ./bin/initials
Enter your full name ('First Middle Last'): john    joe    lee    bin     foo

 name     : john    joe    lee    bin     foo
 initials : J.J.L.B
```

There is no absolute right way to do it. You can make it as robust or as simple as you like as long as it provides the correct initials and avoids errors like reading/writing beyond your array bounds, etc..

Comment: Note that the requested output includes dots separating (but not terminating) the sets of initials.  Your code doesn't handle names like Patrick O'Reilly any better than mine (yours gives PO; mine gives P.O.R — ideally, the output should be P.O'R.  However, that's a refinement beyond the immediate scope of the question.

Comment: Err... kinda blew right past that one eh'. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of `strcat()`

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
```

so this line of yours,

```
strcat(&name[i + 1], initials);
```

is actually copying the uninitialized contents of the `initial[]` array into `name[i+1]`. And I am sure thats not what you want.

Comment: Ok, I switched both name and initials in the arguments. Instead of copying the first letter it copies the entire word after the space. Any idea as to why this is happening? For example if I put "charles robert", instead of concatenating R to the initials string, it concatenates robert to it.